# Where to set Windows Phone 8 icons in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I've upgraded a Windows Phone 7 app to Windows Phone 8/VS2012, and now I can't find where to set up application icons. Weird enough, there is almost no resource on the web about where to set up application icons for my app before publishing. In VS2010/WP7, it was trivial. Now, I've searched almost everywhere and couldn't find anything related to icons. The only one that I can set is the store icon (300x300) via right click and opening marketplace test kit. Either I am too dumb to find it, or it is really somewhere hidden in Visual Studio 2012. How do I edit the icons for my Windows Phone 8 app in Visual Studio 2012?

Thanks,

Can.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look for the "WMAppManifest.xml" file under the "Properties" node of the project in Solution Explorer and double click it.  That should open a visual editor that allows you to choose the various application and tile icons along with changing other properties in the manifest.

Comment: And what needs to be the size of the icon?

Comment: Here's information about the icons: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948(v=vs.105).aspx